# Xcode catch all uncaught exceptions

Tags: xcode, exception, breakpoints, uncaught-exception

In Xcode I can create a breakpoint to catch all exceptions (exception breakpoint). However this breakpoint will also fire in a try-catch situation.

I'm using third party libraries, so the try-catch situation is a fact, not an option.

Is there a way to only handle the **uncaught** exceptions, instead of all exceptions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put a top-level `try/catch` at your threads' entries.

You may also be interested in `NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler`.

Normally, top level handlers are of little utility in production (you're really not attempting to recover from a problem you aren't prepared to handle, but it may be useful for last words or breakpoints). Ideally, you would guard your exits from those library interfaces with a try/catch if and only if you could handle the the exception. Either that, or `nothrow` as a quick debugging utility during development.

If you're trying to catch Cocoa exceptions -- just let it die and file bugs to whoever thought Cocoa exceptions were supposed to be recoverable.

Comment: Thanks. I dug up a bit of info on the NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler: http://cocoawithlove.com/2010/05/handling-unhandled-exceptions-and.html, for other people reading this.

Comment: "Normally, top level handlers are of little utility in production" From my experience they're super valuable for reporting errors in production.